# p5.js api app not returning correct result

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using p5.js to make an API app, which is supposed to have a search bar, and when you click search it will grab an api from the value, and console.log it (for now)

The problem is, when I try to actually click the search bar, the result is always the previous result. In other words, if I first searched "Jack", it would be undefined, and if I then searched "Jill", I would get the result from "Jack".

Here is my code (in p5.js by the way)

The file for grabbing API:

```
let playerdata;

async function grabAPI(player) {
    if(player !== undefined && typeof(player) === "string") {
        await loadPlayer(player)
        
        console.log(playerdata)
    }
}

function loadPlayer(player) {
    let url = `https://api.slothpixel.me/api/skyblock/profile/${player}`
    
    loadJSON(url, dataReceived, dataError)
    
    return playerdata
}

function dataReceived(data) {
    playerdata = data;
    return;
}

function dataError(err) {
    playerdata = `Not Found (Error ${err.status})`;
    return;
}
```

The file for making button, setting up the page, etc:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

let input;
let search;
let nameValid;

function draw() {
    background(255, 255, 255)
    
    if(input == undefined) {
        input = createInput("")
        input.position(200, 200)
    }
    if(search == undefined) {
        search = createButton("Search")
        search.position(400, 200)
        search.mousePressed(buttonPressed)
    }
    if(nameValid !== undefined && nameValid === false) {
        text("not found", 300, 300)
    }
}

function buttonPressed() {
    if(typeof(input.value()) === "string" && input.value() !== "") {
        grabAPI(input.value())
    }
}
```

judging by the fact that the first time I run it, it always is "undefined", I think this is a simple problem of variables not being edited in the proper places, but I can't find where the problem is for the life of me.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why do you create the input/search elements in the draw() function and not the setup() function?

Comment: Additionally, do you ever change the value of nameValid?

Comment: just realised, no i do not, and I don't ever actually need to use nameValid. Thanks, even though that's not really the answer I was looking for